# Twilio SMS Always Shows as Delivered

Tags: twilio

I am testing the SMS message status log in Twilio (python), but I'm finding that all statuses report as "delivered", even if the receiving device is turned off.  Are only particular carriers able to confirm delivery to the handset?  Or am I pulling the wrong status?

```
message = client.messages.create(
    body="Phone off!",  
    to="97.....",
    from_="97.....",
    )

resources = client.messages.list()
for resource in resources:
    print resource.to, resource.status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

The [`Delivered` status](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message#sms-status-values) indicates that we have received a delivery receipt from the upstream carrier.  If the carrier reports it to us, we should show messages that were delivered to powered off handsets as `undelivered`.  Not all carriers return the same data so its possible that the specific carrier you are sending the message is not returning the powered-off state to us.  I'd suggest shooting an email to help@twilio.com and they can work with you to determine what details your specific carrier is returning to Twilio.

Hope that helps.